# VMware ESXi 5.5.0 server - nagios monitoring

Tags: vmware-esxi, nagios

I have a VMware ESXi 5.5.0 server and I want that my Nagios server can monitor it.

How can I install the nagios-tools on the ESXi 5.5.0 server?

Answer (score 3):

You don't really install nagios-tools on an ESXi host. The only thing you actually install are hardware specific VIBs that allow monitoring of the hardware itself.

What VIB you need to install depends on the hardware, usually you can get them from the manufacturer. If you installed the ESXi using an image from the manufacturer the VIBs are usually already preinstalled.

The checks for the hardware and the ESXi specific checks are installed on the Nagios host itself.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use snmp with supported OIDS, better than nrpe and custom scripts, which you need to porting into the system.

You can find howto enable snmpd server on vmware site/google. 
Something like this:

```
esxcli system snmp set --communities YOUR_STRING
esxcli system snmp set --enable true
esxcli network firewall ruleset set --ruleset-id snmp --allowed-all true
esxcli network firewall ruleset set --ruleset-id snmp --enabled true
/etc/init.d/snmpd restart
```

Comment: ok, thanks but what must I add to my Nagios server config that the ESXi will be monitored?

Comment: depends on your desire. What do you want to monitor? SSH/PING - you could monitor whith standart nagios plugin checks. For snmp monitoring you could get mibs for example by snmpwalk:  snmpwalk -v2c -c community server_ip. And monitor it by command check_command check_snmp!-o .OID -C comminity